# How to generate different types of reports using SQLite database in android?

Tags: android, report

I am developing one android application in which I need to generate different types of reports  in various format. I want to generate reports in PDF, XLS, DOC and Text File. All the data are stored in  SQLite database. Please guide me how to implement it in android.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can generate PDF reports by using the following code

```
   import java.io.File;
   import java.io.FileOutputStream;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import java.net.URL;
   import java.util.Date;

   import com.itextpdf.text.Anchor;
   import com.itextpdf.text.BadElementException;
   import com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor;
   import com.itextpdf.text.Chapter;
   import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
   import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
   import com.itextpdf.text.Element;
   import com.itextpdf.text.Font;
   import com.itextpdf.text.Image;
   import com.itextpdf.text.List;
   import com.itextpdf.text.ListItem;
   import com.itextpdf.text.Paragraph;
   import com.itextpdf.text.Phrase;
   import com.itextpdf.text.Section;
   import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfImportedPage;
   import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
   import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
   import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader;
   import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.os.Environment;
   import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Main extends Activity {

private static String FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"firstPdf.pdf";
private static Font catFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 18,
        Font.BOLD);
private static Font redFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
        Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.RED);
private static Font subFont = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 16,
        Font.BOLD);
private static Font smallBold = new Font(Font.FontFamily.TIMES_ROMAN, 12,
        Font.BOLD);
TextView txt1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    txt1=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    try {
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
        document.open();
        addMetaData(document);
        addTitlePage(document);
        addContent(document);
        //createImage();
        document.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void addMetaData(Document document) {
    document.addTitle("My first PDF");
    document.addSubject("Using iText");
    document.addKeywords("Java, PDF, iText");
    document.addAuthor("Lars Vogel");
    document.addCreator("Lars Vogel");
}

private static void addTitlePage(Document document)
        throws DocumentException {
    Paragraph preface = new Paragraph();
    // We add one empty line
    addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
    // Lets write a big header
    preface.add(new Paragraph("Title of the document", catFont));

    addEmptyLine(preface, 1);
    // Will create: Report generated by: _name, _date
    preface.add(new Paragraph(
            "Report generated by: " + System.getProperty("user.name") + ", " + new Date(), //$NON-NLS-1$ //$NON-NLS-2$ //$NON-NLS-3$
            smallBold));
    addEmptyLine(preface, 3);
    preface.add(new Paragraph(
            "This document describes something which is very important ",
            smallBold));

    addEmptyLine(preface, 8);

    preface.add(new Paragraph(
            "This document is a preliminary version and not subject to your license agreement or any other agreement with vogella.de ;-).",
            redFont));

    document.add(preface);
    // Start a new page
    document.newPage();
}

private static void addContent(Document document) throws DocumentException {
    Anchor anchor = new Anchor("ESTIMATING APP", catFont);
    anchor.setName("ESTIMATING APP");

    // Second parameter is the number of the chapter
    Chapter catPart = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);

    Paragraph subPara = new Paragraph("Subcategory 1", subFont);
    Section subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
    subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Hello"));

    subPara = new Paragraph("Subcategory 2", subFont);
    subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
    subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Paragraph 1"));
    subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Paragraph 2"));
    subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("Paragraph 3"));

    // Add a list
    createList(subCatPart);
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
    addEmptyLine(paragraph, 5);
    subCatPart.add(paragraph);

    // Add a table
    createTable(subCatPart);

    // Now add all this to the document
    document.add(catPart);

    // Next section
    anchor = new Anchor("Second Chapter", catFont);
    anchor.setName("Second Chapter");

    // Second parameter is the number of the chapter
    catPart = new Chapter(new Paragraph(anchor), 1);

    subPara = new Paragraph("Subcategory", subFont);
    subCatPart = catPart.addSection(subPara);
    subCatPart.add(new Paragraph("This is a very important message"));

    // Now add all this to the document
    document.add(catPart);

}

private static void createTable(Section subCatPart)
        throws BadElementException {
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);

    // t.setBorderColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
    // t.setPadding(4);
    // t.setSpacing(4);
    // t.setBorderWidth(1);

    PdfPCell c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Job Name:"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Test 001"));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);

    c1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(""));
    c1.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    table.addCell(c1);
    table.setHeaderRows(1);

    table.addCell("Date:");
    table.addCell("1.1");
    table.addCell("");
    table.addCell("Labor Rate:");
    table.addCell("2.2");
    table.addCell("");
    table.addCell("Labor Cost:");
    table.addCell("3.2");
    table.addCell("3.3");

    subCatPart.add(table);

}

private static void createList(Section subCatPart) {
    List list = new List(true, false, 10);
    list.add(new ListItem("First point"));
    list.add(new ListItem("Second point"));
    list.add(new ListItem("Third point"));
    subCatPart.add(list);
}

private static void addEmptyLine(Paragraph paragraph, int number) {
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
        paragraph.add(new Paragraph(" "));
    }
}
```

You can check this **[link](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/SrLAmhk9JAY)** for creating XLS reports.

Comment: Thanks!! I would like to know that is there any API which provides to generate Reports like Jasper Report. I have gone thorough Jasper Report for android [link](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jaspermobile-android). But I am not getting it how exactly its working and implement.Please guide me how to do it. Thanks in andvance.