# Report Generation in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

How do I generate a report from my sqlite database.  My data is taken from a a user from edittext widgets and stored in android sqlite database

Comment: what types of report u want to generate

Comment: Pdf or excel reports

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241068/how-to-generate-different-types-of-reports-using-sqlite-database-in-android

Comment: It's different please

Comment: It is so important to generate effective reports and modern tools in android like the crystal reports.

Comment: have you got a useful solution for that?