# Join data inside a column instead of combining columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have this query that joins all the columns I want:

```
select * from Customer c
inner join Tier t on c.TierId = t.Id
```

However I don't want all the columns combined.  I would like to have a `Tier` column and then have the full tier record in this column (as I am mapping to json and it has to be in this format).

How do I create subgroup like that?

I tried:

```
select *, Tier = (select * from Tier t where t.Id = c.TierId ) from Customer c
inner join Tier t on c.TierId = t.Id
```

can someone point in right direction please.

Edit:

So I want something like this:

```
- CustomerID
- CustomerName
- CreatedDate
- Tier <-- all tier columns as a subgroup like when you group by
    - TierId
    - TierName
```

Comment: `select tier.* from ...`?

Comment: What should the expected output look like?

Comment: Sorry, I am using sqlite

Comment: So what you actually want is to generate a column that contains a JSON object?

Comment: no, the library I am using should handle making it into json for me, I just need to feed in a query that returns the data in the correct structure.  I need a column named Tier that contains the entire tier row

Comment: Which columns from table `TIER` do you want and which columns from table `CUSTOMER`?

Comment: all from both but the tier columns all to be under a column called Tier inside Customer

Comment: @Guerrilla: please show us the result that you expect. You can't have several columns in one single column, unless you do some kind of data manipulation (string concatenation, json object, ...)

Comment: We don't know what columns are in table `TIER` or table `CUSTOMER`. I meant that you should [edit] your question and list the column names. It may also help if you listed the data types as well.

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. It looks to me like you want to create a report. If so, then maybe this SO question will help? [How to generate different types of reports using SQLite database in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15241068/how-to-generate-different-types-of-reports-using-sqlite-database-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to select just one column from `tier`?  Be explicit about the columns you want:

```
select t.tier, c.*
from Customer c inner join
     Tier t
     on c.TierId = t.Id;
```

Comment: Hi I updated my answer.  I want to select all colums as a subgroup

Comment: @Guerrilla . . . I am not aware that such a thing exists in SQL Server.  You could combine them as a JSON string or concat them together or use naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like what you need is sql [CONCAT Function](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-string-functions/sql-server-concat-function/).
The query would look something like that:

```
SELECT CONCAT("[", column1, ", ", column2, "]") AS tier FROM Tier
```

SQLite doesn't support CONCAT so you have to use the || operator like this:

```
SELECT ("[" || column1 || ", " || column2 || "]") AS tier FROM Tier
```

The brackets will mark it as an array in JSON, you can remove them if you want.

You can also add the columnname to the result by just adding them as a string to make it more

NOTE: You won't be able to access the values like an Array because this simply merges the values to a String

Comment: unknown database function CONCAT

Comment: true, i didn't see your edit that you use SQLite and updated my answer now :)